How to create a gRCP Client using C#/.net6/MAUI on Android based on Grpc.Net.Client
I'd like to create a gRCP client on Android using C#/.net6/MAUI.
My code looks like this
var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2Support", true);
GrpcChannel Channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(Endpoint, new GrpcChannelOptions
{
HttpClient = httpClient,
LoggerFactory = loggerFactory
});
var Client = new NonceRequest.NonceRequestClient(Channel);

But as a result I'm getting an execption
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while unable to establish HTTP/2 connection.

My backend is an AWS Loadbalancer for gRPC. Therefore using Grpc.net.client.web is not an option.
When I create the same example using Xamarin and Grpc.Core.Xamarin everything works fine.
I'm currently testing on an older Android Phone (API 27, A10), so I'm unsure if this is an issue as well.
